# How to consume the complex json data using map in javascript

Tags: javascript

here  i have the below json data :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "info": 21,
            "datatype": "string",
            "uid": "00:00:00:02",
            "mainData": {
                "person": "admin",
                "values": [
                    "192.168.0.5",
                    "192.168.0.6"
                ],
                "variable": "maximum",
                "device": "samsung_device"
            },
            "operator": "admin"
        },
        {
            "info": 2,
            "datatype": "string",
            "uid": "00:00:00:05",
            "mainData": {
                "person": "admin",
                "values": [
                    "192.168.0.5",
                    "192.168.0.6"
                ],
                "variable": "maximum",
                "device": ""
            },
            "operator": "admin"
        },   {
            "info": 2,
            "datatype": "string",
            "uid": "00:00:00:05",
            "mainData": {
                "person": "admin",
                "values": [
                    "192.168.0.5",
                    "192.168.0.6"
                ],
                "variable": "maximum",
                "device": ""
            },
            "operator": "admin"
        },
    ]
}
```

what i am trying to achieve is
1. only first i want to retrieve the first index uid value and want to show the value in button and after clicking on that the   uid of the first index then mainData property and values has to be displayed

```
mainData": {
                    "person": "admin",
                    "values": [
                        "192.168.0.5",
                        "192.168.0.6"
                    ]
```

here i tried of `data.['uid'].['maindata].[values]` but it not right away

,

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you are looking for. Maybe you could edit the question and clarify what your final desired result is. One thing is clear though: `data` is an array, so you need to use an index to get the first values: `data[0]. mainData.values` will be the values for the first object.

Comment: @MarkMeyer edited